# DRF ListAPIView custom return not an object

Tags: django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to customise ListAPIView in order to return custom object. By default DRF returns object in an array, I want just a customized object.

```
class PostDetailApiView(ListAPIView, CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get_queryset(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().get_queryset(request, *args, **kwargs)

        return Response({
                'status': 200,
                'message': 'Post delivered!!',
                'data': response.data
            })
```

I'm getting error:

```
lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 120, in __iter__
    'The response content must be rendered before it can be iterated over.'
**django.template.response.ContentNotRenderedError: The response content must be rendered before it can be iterated over.**
[03/May/2020 02:34:14] "GET /en-us/blog/api/posts/VueJS%20blog%20in%20progress HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

The error dissappears when I return an empty array e.g.:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = []
    queryset.append(Post.objects.get(title=self.kwargs["title"]))
    return queryset
```

How could I return an object like this from Class-based views?:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Post created!",
    "data": {}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: If you want a ***single object information***, why don't you use **`rest_framework.generics.RetrieveAPIView`** class?

Comment: if you want get a object instead of list, use `RetrieveAPIView`, remove the MI.

Comment: I didn't know about this class. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
# You just need to override your class from APIView class and write your custom response

from rest_framework.views import APIView

class PostDetailApiView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        title = request.data.get("title")
        post = Post.objects.filter(title=title).values('title')

        return Response({
            'status': 200,
            'message': 'Post delivered!!',
            'data': list(post)
        })
```

Comment: .values() That's what I was missing!  Thanks!